# dice, comparing manual calculation, TI84, R

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I have used a die 100 times.
Here are the results for 1-6 points

observed: 20/12/17/16/20/15
expecting: 16,66 for each

I calculated by hand (df=5), the value is 2,8347

Then I used a pocket calculator (TI 84 plus), the result:
chisquare is 2,834730
p=0,72544
df=5

Finally I used R,

```
observed <-c(20,12,17,16,20,15)
expected <-c(16.7, 16.7,16.7,16.7,16.7,16.7)

dice <-matrix(c(observed, expected),6,2)
chisq.test(dice)
```

the result is:

```
X-squared = 1.4718, df = 5, p-value = 0.9163
```

Did I make a mistake?

Comment: `> dice = c(20,12,17,16,20,15)
> chisq.test(dice)

 Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  dice
X-squared = 2.84, df = 5, p-value = 0.7246`

Comment: `chisq.test(dice)$expected
[1] 16.66667 16.66667 16.66667 16.66667 16.66667 16.66667`

Comment: Notice the expected values when you run the test setting it up the way you `did:chisq.test(dice)$expected
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 18.33167 18.36833
[2,] 14.33566 14.36434
[3,] 16.83317 16.86683
[4,] 16.33367 16.36633
[5,] 18.33167 18.36833
[6,] 15.83417 15.86583`

Comment: In other words, this is a purely software issue: the way you are setting it up prompts R to find expected values for your expected values.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way your table looks the way you set it up:

```
addmargins(dice)
                Sum
     20  16.7  36.7
     12  16.7  28.7
     17  16.7  33.7
     16  16.7  32.7
     20  16.7  36.7
     15  16.7  31.7
Sum 100 100.2 200.2
```

Notice how your intended `expected` values become part of the data to analyze, and how expected values are calculated on top of them:

```
chisq.test(dice)$expected
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 18.33167 18.36833
[2,] 14.33566 14.36434
[3,] 16.83317 16.86683
[4,] 16.33367 16.36633
[5,] 18.33167 18.36833
[6,] 15.83417 15.86583
```

In actuality what you want is to set it up **without** the expected values:

```
> dice = c(20,12,17,16,20,15)
> chisq.test(dice)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  dice
X-squared = 2.84, df = 5, p-value = 0.7246
```

Notice now the correct expected values:

```
> chisq.test(dice)$expected
[1] 16.66667 16.66667 16.66667 16.66667 16.66667 16.66667
```